# Java; Imports & javadoc not attatched

Tags: java, eclipse

so im working with a MMORPG Map editor at the moment, and having trouble loading my cache, and, to be honest, trouble loading the editing software itself.

Now i believe im reasonably close, as ive been using tutorials on stackoverflow to help with the problems ive found(thank you stackoverflow) but ive come to a complete halt caused by an import error which has thrown a bigger error(this is the general error eclipse is giving me):

```
Badseek - pos:70502120 len:112014898
SOMESHITWRONGWITHNEXTFILEtrue true true
Dec 07, 2015 7:35:34 PM com.jme3.app.Application handleError
SEVERE: Uncaught exception thrown in Thread[LWJGL Renderer Thread,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.runescape.net.Buffer.get24BitInt(Buffer.java:152)
at com.runescape.cache.Archive.<init>(Archive.java:28)
at org.fabian.rsmt.RSMapTool.getArchive(RSMapTool.java:74)
at org.fabian.rsmt.RSMapTool.loadCache(RSMapTool.java:296)
at org.fabian.rsmt.RSMapTool.simpleInitApp(RSMapTool.java:125)
at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:226)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:209)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

so when i follow the links, the only thing they all have in common is the imports my source file is using (RSMapTool.java)

This element has no attached Javadoc and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached source.

Now based off that error, im not 100% if my imports are causing in, and if not, then in that case ive got an even bigger error im gonna need help with o.O, but if it is the imports, and someone can make enough sense out of my details provided to give me a run-down on how it should be, that would be great

Things i have tried:

I attached the imports to their respected sources, and figured out how to build a javadoc path(if thats correct) and validated said path, but still got both errors.

Comment: https://github.com/avatarscape/RSMapTool/blob/master/src/org/fabian/rsmt/RSMapTool.java

Comment: thanks jiri, but thats the one i have and im still getting the error :/